# extend a model ActiveRecord with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to extend a ActiveRecord this class. I am using Postgresql

```
class Jobo::Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
class Jobo::Stripe < Provider
# code
end
```

When i am trying to add

self.abstract_class = true

I have got this error

> 2.2.2 :001 > Jobo::Provider.first TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String    from
>   /Users/Michelin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:24:in `quote_ident'    from /Users/Michelin/.rvm/

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `Jobo::Provider` an abstract class means that you can't use it directly, that's what abstract means.